# Reason for check of msg.value > 0

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-design, ether, design-patterns

I came across published smart contracts (like [this one from ConsensSys](https://github.com/ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet)) that check whether `msg.value` is strictly larger than zero in their payable functions.

After wondering whether `msg.value` can be negative, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820812/how-to-check-for-negative-numbers-sent-to-smart-contract) whose answer says that it's not possible.

These checks, therefore, seem unnecessary to me. Is this to make sure not to fall victim to another negative transaction value bug? Do zero-value transactions pose a threat?

Comment: This kind of check makes sense because the `msg.value` cannot be negative but it can be zero or a strictly positive (I.e., `msg.value` is always `>= 0`). So, `msg.value > 0` checks if at least 1 Wei was sent along with the invocation (it is possible to send 0 Weis)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, `0` value transactions pose no threat. However, in practice, it is logical to not accept transactions that do not include any value, especially in transactions whose whole purpose is to transfer value.

Many implementations of requiring a `value` that is greater than `0` do so because of the uniqueness of `0` versus all other numbers. For example, someone my do this because the `value` may be the divisor in an equation at some point in the logic flow, and this would throw (as you cannot divide by 0).

During the design of the ERC20 standard, [there was a long discussion about failing the transaction if no tokens were transferred](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/20). The final decision was made that there are no issues with `0` value transactions, and the tokens that folow the spec allow for this.

Answer (score 1):

The actual code from the link that you've posted (improperly):

```
event Deposit(address indexed sender, uint value);

/// @dev Fallback function allows to deposit ether.
function()
    payable
{
    if (msg.value > 0)
        Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value); // should be preceded by `emit` as of v0.4.21
}
```

The conditional statement in this specific case, is simply in order to avoid emitting the `Deposit` event if the `msg.value` is 0. In other cases, there could be other reasons (my point being, one may wonder about "the inside of the `if` statement", but the condition by itself is "legitimate", since `msg.value` may well be zero).